# getturnstatus() not working

Tags: multiplayer, google-play-games

I am trying to implement a Turn Based Multiplayer game and I have it 90% working but I am getting a strange result from getTurnStatus().

It seems to always return MATCH_TURN_STATUS_THEIR_TURN.  If I exit out of my Game Thread Activity and come back in, it only then detects that it is the player's turn.

I have a MainActivity based on SkeletonActivity example that does the Player Matching etc...

To check the status of the game I call

In Game Thread

int turnStatus = MainActivity.mMatch.getTurnStatus(); //Returns incorrect result

In MainActivity

```
public static TurnBasedMatch mMatch;

    Games.TurnBasedMultiplayer.takeTurn(getApiClient(), mMatch.getMatchId(),
            mTurnData.persist(), nextParticipantId).setResultCallback(
            new ResultCallback<TurnBasedMultiplayer.UpdateMatchResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(TurnBasedMultiplayer.UpdateMatchResult result) {
            processResult(result);
        }
    });



private void processResult(TurnBasedMultiplayer.InitiateMatchResult result) {
    TurnBasedMatch match = result.getMatch();
    mMatch = result.getMatch();
    dismissSpinner();

    if (!checkStatusCode(match, result.getStatus().getStatusCode())) {
        return;
    }

    if (match.getData() != null) {
        updateMatch(match);
        return;
    }


    startMatch(match);
}
```

Any ideas?

I can also see from with my GameThread that

```
    String nameMatch = MainActivity.mMatch.getMatchId();
    int numberMatch = MainActivity.mMatch.getMatchNumber();
    Log.d("updateMultiWait","nameMatch = "+nameMatch);
    Log.d("updateMultiWait","numberMatch = "+numberMatch);
```

Displays in Logcat

nameMatch = ChEKCQjf7I234789234WieaM0dnEzuQB
numberMatch = 1
MATCH_TURN_STATUS_THEIR_TURN

Comment: To add to this.  I am receiving updates from the listener and processResult gets called but only for the player that is taking the turn.  Other players do not receive any update and any call to getturnstatus() or even calling getdata() returns stale data.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I figured it out and I am posting this in case anyone else has the same issue.  This is not very well documented by Google IMO.

You have to not only create a listener, but you also have to register it in order to receive updates.

I did this as follows:

```
            Games.TurnBasedMultiplayer.registerMatchUpdateListener(MainActivity.mHelper.getApiClient(), this);
```

Now I get updated when another player takes a turn.  You then need to use the updated match data that will be returned in the relevant listener process and use that to update your turn data.  Then when you take your turn, you will persist the new turn data.  Rinse and repeat.